# How can I get the minimum ratio between of each pair of rows with distance n, for all n from 0 up to the length of the dataframe (minus 1)?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, pandas

I'm trying to do an operation on each pair of rows of distance n, and get the minimum (also maximum and mean) of the results for each n from 0 to n-1. For example, if Data=[1,2,3,4] and the operation is addition, Minimum=[2,3,4,5] and Maximum=[8,7,6,5], and Mean=[5,5,5,5].

I have the following code that uses ratio as the operation which works OK for a small data size but takes more than 10 seconds for 10,000 rows. Since I will be working with data that can have 1,000,000 rows, what would be a better way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

low=250
high=5000
length=10

x=pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.uniform(low, high=high, size=length)})
x['mean']=x['min']=x['max']=x['A'].copy()

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    ratio=x['A']/x['A'].shift(i)
    x['mean'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.mean()
    x['max'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.max()
    x['min'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.min()

print (x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** For efficiency and considering that you might have upto `1,000,000 rows`, I would suggest using the underlying array data in a similar-looking loopy solution and using the efficient array-slicing to use a gradually diminishing data to work with and these two together should bring on noticeable performance boost.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
a = x['A'].values
N = len(a)
out = np.zeros((N,4))
out[:,0] = a
for i in range(N):
    ratio = a[i:]/a[:N-i]
    out[i,1] = ratio.mean()
    out[i,2] = ratio.min()
    out[i,3] = ratio.max()
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns= (('A','mean','min','max')))
```

**Approach #2 :** For a smaller datasize, we can use a vectorized solution that would create a square `2D` array of shape `(N,N)` with shifted versions of the input data. Then, we  mask out the upper triangular region with `NaNs` and finally employ `numpy.nanmean`, `numpy.nanmin` and `numpy.nanmax` to perform those pandas equivalent `mean`, `min` and `max` equivalent operations -

```
a = x['A'].values
N = len(a)
r = np.arange(N)
shifting_idx = (r[:,None] - r)%N
vals = a[:,None]/a[shifting_idx]

upper_tri_mask = r[:,None] < r
vals[upper_tri_mask] = np.nan

out = np.zeros((N,4))
out[:,0] = a
out[:,1] = np.nanmean(vals, 0)
out[:,2] = np.nanmin(vals, 0)
out[:,3] = np.nanmax(vals, 0)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns= (('A','mean','min','max')))
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def org_app(x):
    x['mean']=x['min']=x['max']=x['A'].copy()
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        ratio=x['A']/x['A'].shift(i)
        x['mean'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.mean()
        x['max'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.max()
        x['min'].iloc[[i]]=ratio.min()
    return x

def app1(x):    
    a = x['A'].values
    N = len(a)
    out = np.zeros((N,4))
    out[:,0] = a
    for i in range(N):
        ratio = a[i:]/a[:N-i]
        out[i,1] = ratio.mean()
        out[i,2] = ratio.min()
        out[i,3] = ratio.max()
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns= (('A','mean','min','max')))
```

Timings -

```
In [3]: low=250
   ...: high=5000
   ...: length=10000
   ...: x=pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.uniform(low, high=high, size=length)})
   ...: 

In [4]: %timeit app1(x)
1 loop, best of 3: 185 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit org_app(x)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.59 s per loop

In [6]: 8590.0/185
Out[6]: 46.432432432432435
```

**`46x+`** speedup on `10,000` rows data!